# Spring JdbcCursorItemReader in spring batch application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

My use case is as follows:
There is an Employee table and columns are as follows:

```
employee_id;
empoyee_dob;
employee_lastName;
employee_firstName;
employee_zipCode
```

Now there is an use-case to build a list of Employees present in Dept 'A' and zipcode 11223 and also employees present in Dept B and zipcode 33445.

I have configured a spring job as follows:

```
<batch:job id="EmployeeDetailsJob" job-repository="EmpDaoRepository">
        <batch:step id="loadEmployeeDetails" >
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="EmployeeDAOTranManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="EmpDaoJdbcCursorItemReader" writer="EmpDaoWriter" commit-interval="200" skip-limit="100">
                  <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                  </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                </batch:chunk>
                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="EmpDaoStepListener" />
                </batch:listeners>
                <batch:transaction-attributes isolation="DEFAULT" propagation="REQUIRED" timeout="300" />
            </batch:tasklet>
     </batch:step>      
    </batch:job>
```

The configuration of reader is as follows:

```
<bean id="EmpDaoJdbcCursorItemReader" class="EmpDaoJdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="EmpDataSource" />
        <property name="sql">
            <value><![CDATA[select  * from Employee where employee_id=? and employee_zipCode=? ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="fetchSize" value="100"></property>
        <property name="rowMapper" ref="EmployeeMapper" />
    </bean>
```

There is class `EmployeeQueryCriteria` which has two fields `employee_id` and `employee_zipCode`.

In on of the steps i will create an `ArrayList` of `EmployeeQueryCriteria` objects for which the data has to be fetched.

So my question is:
1.Is there a way i can pass this List to the `EmpDaoJdbcCursorItemReader` and it will iterate through the object and set the parameter values from the `EmployeeQueryCriteria` object
2.Can i loop through the step to read data for every item in the ArrayList created containing `EmployeeQueryCriteria` and fetch the data.

The class EmpDaoJdbcCursorIte‌​mReader:

```
public class EmpDaoJdbcCursorIte‌​mReader extends JdbcCursorItemReader{
    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution)
    {
    StringBuffer sqlQuerySB= new StringBuffer(super.getSql());
    sqlQuerySB.append((").append(/*I am adding a comma seperated list of employee ids*/).append(")");
        super.setSql(sqlQuerySB.toString());
    }
}
```

My Spring configurations are as follows:

```
Spring-batch-core 2.2.2
Spring-beans 3.2.3
Spring-context 3.2.3
```

Can someone please provide suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please add the code for the `EmpDaoJdbcCursorItemReader` class. And why are you using a custom reader rather than the out-of-the-box `JdbcCursorItemReader`?

Comment: Hello Sir,The reason i am using a custom reader is because currently i am pulling details of all employees with a lsit of employee ids.Since i did not not find a way to us the IN clause with ParamSetter, i am using this customer class, and in the @Before step , setting the sql .I have updated the main post with code for the custom reader.

Comment: Where does the list come from? Are you aware that databases often have a limit to an IN-clause? Oracle's limit, for example, is 1000.

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for your response . Yes I am aware of the limit but in production we don't expect the number of employee ids to be more than 200 at any given run.Having said that I am also looking to see if I can use the RepeatStatus.Continueable , I know it can be used in Tasklet but I am not sure how to use it in  JDBCCursorItem reader.The list for IN clause is coming from another table which I am querying

Comment: Also Sir can you please guide what would be a better approach here to solve this problem .do you think there is an alternative to use the IN clause , one alternate approach I thought is to use a Spring Tasklet and perform the read operation there and use the RepeatStaus.Continueable but in that case I will lose out the advantage of reader and writer and every time I read , I will be creating a big collection of Javs objects which might lead to OOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate through the steps by following code model

```
<decision id="testLoop" decider="iterationDecider">
        <next on="CONTINUABLE" to="pqrStep" />
        <end on="FINISHED" />
</decision>
<step id="pqrStep" next="xyzStep">
        <tasklet ref="someTasklet" />
    </step>
<step id="xyzStep" next="testLoop">
        <tasklet ref="someOtherTasklet" />
</step>
```

and Configuration is

```
<bean id="iterationDecider" class="com.xyz.StepFlowController" />
```

Following class will handle the flow based on the condition

```
public class StepFlowController implements JobExecutionDecider{

@Override
public FlowExecutionStatus decide(JobExecution jobExecution, StepExecution stepExecution) {
    FlowExecutionStatus status = null;
    try {
        if (conditionIsTrue) {
        status = new FlowExecutionStatus("CONTINUABLE");
    }else {
        status = new FlowExecutionStatus("FINISHED");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Hello Mr.Bhaji, thanks for your time in providing a response. One question i have is , in the steps you have mentioned , it is being executed by a tasklet, how can i do the same logic for chunk based processing using a JdbcCursorIte‌​mReader and a DB writer.
Thanks

Comment: instead of Tasklet you can write chunk based tasklet like the following code snippet
  <step id="pqrStep" next="xyzStep">
   <tasklet>
    <chunk reader="testReader" writer="testWriter" commit-interval="300"></chunk>
   </tasklet>
   <listeners>
    <listener ref="testListener" />
   </listeners>
  </step>
  
If you feel this is not what you are expecting let me know exact problem

Comment: Hello Sir, sorry about the late reply , yeah this solution you suggested fits into my plan, thank you very much.